# Java and matching by cucumber expression

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I use cucumber-jvm in external framework

I need code for match cucumber steps and Gherkin sentence. In cucumber-jvm, how to match the good expression. I need this, because in V2.x.x is it regep (not cucumber expression).

Gherkin: `I wait 3 seconds.` match with `@Then("I wait {int} second(s)\\.")`

Gherkin: `I wait 1 second.` match with `@Then("I wait {int} second(s)\\.")`

```
public boolean match(String cucumberExp, String gerkinSentence) {
   boolean result = false;
    ????
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I find this in unit test of cucumber-jvm if help you:

```
@Test
public void unknown_target_type_does_no_transform_data_table() {
    StepExpression expression = new StepExpressionFactory(registry).createExpression("Given some stuff:", UNKNOWN_TYPE);
    List<Argument> match = expression.match("Given some stuff:", table);
    assertEquals(DataTable.create(table), match.get(0).getValue());
}
```

Comment: is that helping to create your method? https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

Comment: I know this documentation well. it's a documentation for a user. My question is how to do the matching (not as a user but as a dev)?

Comment: I want to use the matcher present in cucumber-jvm code to do something else. I am not looking for documentation on the use of cucumber-jvm.

Comment: Look around on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, your link is github home page of cucumber-jvm. can you post your around please?

Comment: Look at the source code.

Comment: I'm already looking there, that does not answer the question. Do you think I found or unit test?

Comment: You are going to have to do some digging.  E.g. Look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/b6586cbce1ef8c2064152fd1e2f40613a2ddb86c/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/Shellwords.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
private static List<?> match(String expressionString, String text) {
    Expression expression;
    ParameterTypeRegistry parameterTypeRegistry = new ParameterTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);
    expression = new CucumberExpression(expressionString, parameterTypeRegistry);
    List<Argument<?>> args = expression.match(text);
    if (args == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Argument<?> arg : args) {
            Object value = arg.getValue();
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

You can valid this solution with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String res = new Gson().toJson(match("I expect to have {string} with the text {string}(\\?)", "I expect to have 'foo' with the text 'foo'?"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I expect to have {string} with the text {string}(\\?)", "I expect to have 'foo' with the text 'foo'"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I wait {int} second(s)(\\?)", "I wait 1 second?"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I wait {int} second(s)(\\?)", "I wait 1 second"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I wait {int} second(s)(\\?)", "I wait 2 seconds?"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I wait {int} second(s)(\\?)", "I wait 2 seconds"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I wait {int} second(s)(\\?)", "I wait 2 seconds!")); //false
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("I poc", "I poc"));
    System.out.println(res);
    res = new Gson().toJson(match("If {string} matches {string}, While {string} respects {string} I do with {int} max tries:", "If 'foo' matches '.+', While 'demo.DemoPage-big_title' respects 'This is a demo for NORAUI.*' I do with 3 max tries:"));
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

result is:

```
["foo","foo"]
["foo","foo"]
[1]
[1]
[2]
[2]
null
[]
["foo",".+","demo.DemoPage-big_title","This is a demo for NORAUI.*",3]
```